# Interchangability of expected value and integral only when $\mathbb E|X(t)| < \infty$ for a stochastic process $\{ X(t) \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stochastic-processes, expected-value, fubini-tonelli-theorems

In my textbook of *Stochastic Process* (in Chinese), I found a theorem as follows:

> **Theorem**: If a stochastic process $\{ X(t), t \ge 0 \}$ has $\mathbb E|X(t)| < \infty$ and $\mathrm{var} X(t) < \infty$, then
> $$\mathbb E \left[ \int_0^t X(s) \, ds \right] = \int_0^t \mathbb E [ X(s) ] \, ds, \\ \mathbb E\left[ \int_0^s \int_0^t X(v) X(u) \, du dv \right] = \int_0^s \int_0^t \mathbb E[X(v)X(u)] \, du dv$$

My textbook says this can be simply proved by applying Fubini's theorem.

But I am confused. To apply Fubini's theorem, we seem to need a condition like $\int_0^t \mathbb E |X(t)| < \infty$ as in [this](https://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Integral.html). Only $\mathbb E|X(t)| < \infty$ is really enough?

I doubt this, but I have no idea how to construct a counterexample. So I ask here, thanks for any help!

Comment: The argument would be valid if $X:[0,t]\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is jointly measurable

Comment: @OliverDíaz I am curious how does one apply Fubini here? Can you please provide a proof or at least some hint?

Comment: If $X$ is jointly measurable, then the proof is as you mentioned, an application of Fubini's theorem. Your textbook may be referring to a process that has some nice properties (cad lag process for instance) that make $X)t$ to be progressively measurable and so jointly measurable when restricted to $\Omega\timesp0,T]$

Comment: @OliverDíaz Yeah, joint measurability is needed and I think joint integrability is also needed, i.e., $\int_0^t \mathbb E|X(t)| < \infty$. Otherwise, I could give a counterexample (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "theorem" is not correct. Here I could give a counterexample.

First, we can construct a discrete stochastic process $\{ Y_n, n \ge 1 \}$.

We consider $$\mathbb{P}(A) := \sum_{k \in A} 2^{-k}, A \subseteq \mathbb{N}^+$$ as the probability measure.
And define $$Y_n(k) := \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 2^k, & k = n \\ -2^k, & k = n - 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$

We could verify that $\{ Y_n, n \ge 1 \}$ satisfies the conditions in the "theorem": $$\mathbb E|Y_n| \le 2^k 2^{-k} + 2^k 2^{-k} = 2 < \infty$$ $$\mathrm{var} Y_n \le \mathbb E Y_n^2 \le 2^{2n} 2^{-n} + 2^{2n - 2} 2^{-(n - 1)} < 2^{n + 1} < \infty$$

However, $$\mathbb E \left[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty Y_n \right] = \mathbb E \left[ k \mapsto Y_n(k) + Y_{n + 1}(k) \right] = \mathbb E [0] = 0$$

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[Y_n] = 1 + \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \left( 2^k 2^{-k} - 2^{k - 1} 2^{-(k - 1)} \right) = 1 \not= \mathbb E \left[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty Y_n \right]$$

$$\mathbb E\left[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{m = 1}^\infty Y_n Y_m \right] = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (Y_k(k)Y_k(k) + Y_{k + 1}(k)Y_k(k) + Y_k(k)Y_{k+1}(k) + Y_{k + 1}(k)Y_{k + 1}(k)) \mathbb P(k) = 0$$

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \mathbb E [ Y_n Y_m ] = \mathbb E [Y_1Y_2] + \mathbb E[Y_1Y_2] + \sum_{n = 2}^\infty (\mathbb E[Y_nY_{n - 1}] + \mathbb E[Y_nY_n] + \mathbb E[Y_nY_{n + 1}]) = -\frac{1}{2} \not= \mathbb E\left[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{m = 1}^\infty Y_n Y_m \right]$$

Second, we can show that it is possible to generalize this construction to the continuous stochastic process.

Define $$X(t) := \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 0, & t = 0 \\ n(n + 1)Y_n, & t \in (\frac{1}{n + 1}, \frac{1}{n}] \end{array} \right.$$

Under this definition, $$\mathbb{E}|X(t)| \le \mathbb{E} \left| \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{t} + 1\right)Y_n \right| \le \frac{2(t + 1)}{t^2} < \infty$$ $$\mathrm{var} [X(t)] \le \mathbb E X^2(t) \le \mathbb E \left[ \left(\frac{t + 1}{t}\right)^2 Y_n^2 \right] < \left( \frac{t + 1}{t} \right)^2 2^\frac{t + 1}{t} < \infty$$

However,
$$\mathbb E \left[ \int_0^1 X(s) \, ds \right] = \mathbb E \left[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n(n + 1)Y_n \left( \frac{1}{n} 
 - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right) \right] = \mathbb E \left[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty Y_n \right] = 0$$

$$\int_0^1 \mathbb E [X(s)] \, ds = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb E[n(n + 1)Y_n] \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb E Y_n = 1 \not= \mathbb E \left[ \int_0^1 X(s) \, ds \right]$$

$$0 = \mathbb E \left[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{m = 1}^\infty Y_n Y_m \right] = \mathbb E \left[ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 X(v) X(u) dudv \right] \not= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \mathbb E [X(v)X(u)] dudv = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \mathbb E[Y_nY_m] = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $X(s) \geq 0$ for all $s$ and jointly measurable then the conclusion is true. You can indeed swap the integral and expectation by Tonelli's theorem.

Further if $\int_{0}^t E(|X(s)|) <\infty$ (OR) $E \int_{0}^t |X(s)| <\infty$ then also the conclusion is true by Fubini-Tonelli's theorem.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#:~:text=Fubini's%20theorem%20implies%20that%20two,one%20integrable%20over%20their%20domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=Fubini%27s%20theorem%20implies%20that%20two,one%20integrable%20over%20their%20domains).

See the above link for other versions.